# App crashes after UITextView scrolls

Tags: iphone, ios, networking, crash, uitextview

**Background**

My app takes data off a network stream, and changes values of UI elements on the screen. One element is a UITextView, which serves as a sort of log for the incoming data. It is supposed to update whenever the app receives a "HasBytesAvailable" NSStreamEvent with the nature of the data incoming. (eg if the data that comes in has to do with cake, the textview would update with something like "6/22/12 8:00 - got cake") An example of how it updates is shown below.

```
[logString insertString:@"This is an update\n" atIndex:0]; 
//logstring is a MutableString I use to hold my UITextView's text
[logString insertString:timeString atIndex:0]; //timestring is current time
logView.text = logString; //logView is my UITextView
[logView flashScrollIndicators];

//logstring and logview declaration and implementation
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITextView *logView;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableString *logString;

logString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"-logging started\n"];
```

**The Problem**

The updating works as I want it as long as I don't try to scroll the TextView. However, if I scroll through the text and hold it down, presumably long enough for my update code to be called, the app crashes when I stop scrolling. I can flick through the text just fine, it's just when it has to handle an incoming packet and I'm still scrolling that it will crash. Furthermore, while I'm scrolling, nothing else will update. All the labels that are supposed to be updated by the data received stay the same.

**My Thoughts**

It's as if the app can't handle both scrolling and working with incoming data at the same time. I'm not sure if this is because I am doing something wrong with memory management, or I need to overwrite some scrolling function, or something else entirely. Any help or thoughts is appreciated.

**Solution**

As trumpetlicks said, I needed to implement multithreading for my network tasks
to do this I did the following:

in initialization:

```
NSOperationQueue *networkQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(initNetworkCommunication) object:nil];
[networkQueue addOperation:operation];
[operation release];
```

in initNetworkCommunication, after initializing CFSocketpair and streams:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run]; //necessary to handle stream events
```

Comment: It makes sense to me that, while you are actively scrolling, the UI thread is busy and isn't going to do other updates.  (I assume your networking is happening in some other thread.)  What does the crash look like (exception & stack)?

Comment: How Hefty is your network traffic?  It doesnt seem like a light network load should cause what you are seeing, if it is a HEAVY load, then that is another question!

Comment: @trumpetlicks It shouldn't be the traffic load, we're talking about 64 bytes per message, coming in about once a second.

Comment: @PhillipMills what's odd is that there is no crash according to the debugger console. It just quits. I put in a NSLog and you are definitely correct, it isn't handling the stream events while it handles the scrolling event. Is there a way for me to make it handle both?

Comment: Is it crashing of simply stalling the scrolling?  Further question, is it crashing / stalling when there is very little text in your logView, or just after a while when there is quite a bit of text?

Comment: @trumpetlicks There has to be enough text for the view to be able to scroll, but that isn't all that much (the view is only 280x240) so I don't think it's overflowing memory. It seems to be crashing - it exits to the home screen at least, but there is no crash message. It may be worth including that I do some byte level operations with the data I get from the packet (byte swapping and such), and I don't know if Xcode handles memory errors on that level well.

Comment: I would have to see more code surrounding where the string you are using to fill your logView is initially generated, what threads and how they are implemented for your comm. stuff, etc...?  I do see that you are calling "retain" after every update.  That worries me a bit.  Very rarely have I EVER had to call retain on an NSString object.

Comment: @trumpetlicks Yes, I don't think the retain is necessary. I took it out because I realized that was actually left over from troubleshooting this problem earlier. I updated the question with some of my implementation. However, I don't know how to work with threads, and that could be my problem! could you point me towards some resource for managing threads on ios?

Comment: Start here.  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html   You may also wish to add your networking setup and usage code so that we can all see what you are doing there!!!

Comment: @trumpetlicks haha this is a stupid question, but how do I select your response as the correct answer? This is what my problem is, I need to put my network and gui processes on seperate threads.

Comment: Thanks much for the upvote and check!!!  I have posted it as an answer :-)  +1 on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start here.

developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/… You may

also wish to add your networking setup and usage code so that we can all see what you are doing there!!!

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest 3 ideas that can help you:

1) DONT call UI elements from background threads, go ALWAYS on main thread, so for example use:

```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

         self.textview.text = .....

    });
```

2) use some kind of sync between threads (more on later..)

3) NSOperation is too complex for this task, simply use NSURLSession callbacks AND in completion call a "central" method that you must serialize (as said in 2))

Suppose in every network call back:

```
...
    // create Session and request...
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                NSString * s = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                [self serializer:s];
                                            }
                                  ];
    [task resume];
...
```

4) Now let' try to synchronize (and going to the main thread for UI..)

in "init"/ViewDidLoad create a

```
self.queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.acme.myQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
```

5)use it in serializer method:

```
-(void) serializer:(NSString*)s
{
    dispatch_barrier_async(self.queue, ^{
        [self updateUI:s];
    });
}
```

6) update UI:

```
-(void) updateUI:(NSString*)s
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSString * currText = self.textView.text;
        self.textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", currText, s];

    });
}
```

so to recap all my controller can be (some details are left to you..)

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property dispatch_queue_t queue;
@property UITextView * textView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.acme.myQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);

    [self startDownloadFromURL:@"https://www.apple.com"];
    [self startDownloadFromURL:@"https://www.google.com"];
}


-(void)startDownloadFromURL:(NSString*)urlString{

    NSURLSession * session;
    NSURLRequest * request;

    // create Session and request...
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                NSString * s = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                [self serializer:s];
                                            }
                                  ];
    [task resume];
}

-(void) serializer:(NSString*)s
{
    dispatch_barrier_async(self.queue, ^{
        [self updateUI:s];
    });
}


-(void) updateUI:(NSString*)s
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSString * currText = self.textView.text;
        self.textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", currText, s];

    });
}





@end
```